# Sort By # in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, sorting

What is Sort By: # option that is available in Windows 8? A screenshot of it is given below:

[image: Sort By # in Windows 8]

Comment: The same option is available in Windows 7 in Music type folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means Sort by Track Number. It's mostly used for audio CDs or audio files with Track Number info.